# Extracting data from different points within a string

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the date from a column which includes the date alongside other information about the file. Unfortunately in some cases the date is at the beginning of the row but in others it is mid-way through the string, as shown.

| Row | Filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK |
| 2 | 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK |
| 3 | hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK |
| 4 | hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK |
| 5 | 2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK |
| 6 | 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK |

I want to create a new column with the extracted date

| Row | Filename | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK | 2007-11-05 |
| 2 | 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK | 2008-09-24 |
| 3 | hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK | 2008-09-24 |
| 4 | hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK | 2008-09-24 |
| 5 | 2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK | 2007-11-0 |
| 6 | 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK | 2008-09-24 |

Before I realised that some of the dates were buried in other data I was extracting the first 10 characters, but that clearly doesn't work any more.

```
df %>%
mutate(Date = substr(filename,1,10))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please share your data or a reproducible example rather than a table. For example : try `dput(df)` and paste the output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` & `stringr` solution.  Note that this will only get the first date in the string.  If there are multiple dates, more care is necessary.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

# extract just the date
df %>% 
  mutate(
    date = 
      str_match(
        Filename,
        pattern = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'
      ),
    date = as.Date(date)
  )
#>   Row                       Filename       date
#> 1   1           2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK 2007-11-05
#> 2   2           2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK 2008-09-24
#> 3   3 hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK 2008-09-24
#> 4   4 hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK 2008-09-24
#> 5   5           2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK 2007-11-05
#> 6   6           2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK 2008-09-24
```

I made a few assumptions about your data, but if you're also interested in the other columns, you can use `tidyr::separate_wider_delim()`

```r
df %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(
    cols = Filename,
    names = c('col1', 'date', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'),
    delim = ' ',
    too_few = 'align_end'
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>     Row col1      date       col2  col3  col4 
#>   <int> <chr>     <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 <NA>      2007-11-05 KJ    2     JUHK 
#> 2     2 <NA>      2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK 
#> 3     3 hki083892 2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK 
#> 4     4 hki083892 2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK 
#> 5     5 <NA>      2007-11-05 KJ    2     JUHK 
#> 6     6 <NA>      2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK
```

Or if you need to get really specific with your separation, you can try `tidyr::separate_wider_regex()`.

```r
patterns <-
  c(
    'col1' = r'(|\w{3}\d{6}\s)',
    'date' = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s)',
    'col2' = r'(\w{2}\s)',
    'col3' = r'(\d\s)',
    'col4' = r'(\w{4})'
  )

df %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(
    cols = Filename,
    patterns = patterns,
    too_few = 'align_start'
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      everything(),
      str_trim # get rid of leftover whitespace
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   Row   col1        date       col2  col3  col4 
#>   <chr> <chr>       <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     ""          2007-11-05 KJ    2     JUHK 
#> 2 2     ""          2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK 
#> 3 3     "hki083892" 2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK 
#> 4 4     "hki083892" 2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK 
#> 5 5     ""          2007-11-05 KJ    2     JUHK 
#> 6 6     ""          2008-09-24 KM    2     JUHK
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Filename = c(
    '2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK',
    '2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK',
    'hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK',
    'hki083892 2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK',
    '2007-11-05 KJ 2 JUHK',
    '2008-09-24 KM 2 JUHK'
  )
)

#highly subjest stringr 
library(stringr)

#"this is your regex pattern, you would see d is a digit and the {} indicates how many
date_pattern <- "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"

# Extract
data$Date <- str_extract(data$Filename, date_pattern)

# Print e
print(data)
```